# Is there a difference between the solar elevation angle and sun declination?

Tags: the-sun, declination, sun-rays

I need to use the sunrise equation but one of the variables is the sun declination. On the other hand, I have the values for solar elevation angle that I need. Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elevation and Declination are from different co-ordinate systems, so solar elevation is given in Alt/Az co-ordinates and refers to the elevation above the local horizon. Sun declination is measured in RA/Dec co-ordinates (which is an equatorial co-ordinate system) and measures the Sun's inclination above or below the equator on the celestial sphere.

Comment: Is there a way to convert between the two?

Comment: @Goldname You might find this tool useful https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/azel.html